# How to get a collection of control by its type in xpages

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

Is it possible to get a collection of control by its type, eg.  Label, dojo control likes edit box, combo box etc.  In general, I wanted to get a collection of 10 Label controls from an extlib dialog box.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

XPages is build on JSF, so yes.  You start with the enclosing element (the xp:view if you want all) and walk through the children. The class names are what you are looking for. 
Check the XPages Debug Toolbar project on OpenNTF for sample code.

To be clear: JSF organizes controls in trees, so you need to recursively call getChildren() until there are no more left to get all of them. The Debug Toolbar did all this, so go get the sources.

The code you're looking is in the getComponentIds() function in the xpDebugToolbar script library. It was originally written by Tommy Valand for his API Inspector.

Comment: Thank you.  I did try to getComponent("tableId").getChildren but return all the rows.  I was expecting all the Labels and their target control Ids in from this table.  I still not really understand about xpages.  I tried to search for sample code on OpenNTF but overwhelming with tons of documents but no luck :-)  Could you please more specific.  I am actually looking something likes getElementbyType("Label control") using ssjs.  Big thanks

Comment: This is a very useful site to get an idea: http://blog.ecafechat.com/useless-documentation/

Comment: Hi Dragon, can you provide your solution here? Others might have the question too and only knowing that you succeeded isn't nice. How you succeeded would be much nicer!

Comment: The children of a table are rows - that is correct. JSF organizes controls in trees - so you get the children of the rows which will be cells and then their children

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code.

```
var myUtil = {
    myArray : new Array(),

    getComponentIDsByType : function(parentComp, parent, className) {
        /*
        parentComp: getComponent("controlId") or view for all
        parent: null or parent of parentComp
        className: class name of component
        Example of usage:
        wnUtil.getComponentIDsByType(getComponent("tableId"), null, "com.ibm.xsp.OutputLabel");
        wnUtil.getComponentIDsByType(getComponent("tableId"), null, "com.ibm.xsp.extlib.dojo.form.FilteringSelect");
        wnUtil.getComponentIDsByType(view, null, "com.ibm.xsp.extlib.dojo.form.FilteringSelect");       
        */
        var itr = parentComp.getChildren().iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            var c:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspScriptCollector = itr.next();
            if(!parent) parent = parentComp;
            var p = parentComp;
            if(p && p.getId() && !p.getId().match(/^_id/i) && !p.getId().match(/^event/i) && !p.getId().match(/^selectItem/i) && !p.getId().match(/^dateTimeHelper/i) && !p.getId().match(/^br/i)) {
                parent = parentComp;
            }
            if(c.getId() && !c.getId().match(/^_id/i) && !c.getId().match(/^event/i) && !c.getId().match(/^selectItem/i) && !c.getId().match(/^dateTimeHelper/i) && !c.getId().match(/^br/i) && !c.getId().match(/^typeAhead/i) && !c.getRendererType().equalsIgnoreCase('com.ibm.xsp.PassThroughTagRenderer')) {
                //d.replaceItemValue("control", c.getId());
                //if(parent) d.replaceItemValue("parent", parent.getId());
                //d.replaceItemValue("type", this.getType(c.getRendererType()));
                if (c.getRendererType() == className) {
                    //print (c.getId() + "<<<>>" + c.getRendererType());
                    // store component id to an array
                    this.myArray.push(c.getId());
                }           
            }
            this.getComponentIDsByType(c, parent, className);
        }
    }   
}
```

Then you just iterate through the myUtil.myArray